# Android capture played sound

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediaplayer

I wrote a simple Android app that plays two to wav files at once mixed. My solution is similar to 
[Android: Mixing multiple AudioTrack instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425526/android-mixing-multiple-audiotrack-instances), I simply play the two files in two different threads using the AudioTrack class.

Now I would like also to save the result on file, does have someone any idea on how can I achieve this?

Is there any way to capture the played sound? Or maybe I have to redirect the audio played on file?

Can someone help me?

Thanks