# Android Multitrack Audio Library?

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording, mixing

Hi Guys I am trying to build a "4-track" recording app on Android.

I'm looking for a library or set of classes I can use record audio and mix 4 channels of audio to a 2 channel "mixdown".

Ideally it would be similar to the [javax.sound.sampled library](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/audio_playing_recording.html).

Low latency is also important...

I am new to Android development and have only worked in web dev for a year (c#, jquery, sql, vb).

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to do an implementation of AudioTrack. This will give you the most control.

Ref:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

[Android: Mixing multiple AudioTrack instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425526/android-mixing-multiple-audiotrack-instances)